# Why does the /tab is not working when I deployed it to azure?

Tags: microsoft-teams

Hi I'm new to teams development. So I created an app and tried it in teams via the localhost:3000, it is working fine.

But when I deployed the app to my azure the /tab and /config is not working. Do I have a problem in code? deployment? or do I need to configure something in my webserver?

Edit:
when I try to go to [www.example.com/tab](http://www.example.com/tab) this is what it returns:

The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider about your routes. When you upload it to globally.

Comment: Hi, so I'm new to this environment I used the MS teams toolkit in visual codes, And it has all the routes pre-coded when you create an app like this:

`<Router>
      <Route exact path="/privacy" component={Privacy} />
      <Route exact path="/termsofuse" component={TermsOfUse} />
      <Route exact path="/tab" component={Tab} />
      <Route exact path="/config" component={TabConfig} />
    </Router>`

I'm a bit lost because when I try it in localhost it work just fine and when I deploy it to azure suddenly its stop working. Does the routes changes when you deploy it?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by:

Creating a web.config file in public folder that contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
<rules>
<rule name="React Routes" stopProcessing="true">
<match url=".*" />
<conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
<add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
</conditions>
<action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
</rule>
</rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Then npm run build
lastly, deploy the build folder.